# Apply aggregate function to certain columns using SQL in Apache Druid

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, druid

I have a table like this

```
----------------------
code    sales    goal
----------------------
  b       7       20
  b      12       20
  a       9       15
  c       4        3
  a       4       15
```

And I want to perform an agg function to group by a sum only on 'sales' column, because 'goal' column is common to a given value in 'code' column to get something more like this

```
---------------------------------
code    total    goal
---------------------------------
  b       19      20
  a       13      15
  c        4       3
```

Is there a way to perform something like this?

```
SELECT code, SUM(sales) AS total, goal FROM such_table GROUP BY code
```

To then operate the columns to achieve the following future operations:

```
------------------------------------------------------
code    sum(sales)   intact(goal)  achvd(100*sum/goal)
------------------------------------------------------
  b         19           20               95
  a         13           15               86.6
  c          4            3              133.3
```

Comment: If you are sure for each code the goal is the same, you could put `MAX(goal)` in your `select` statement; If you are not so sure, put `code, goal` in your `group by` statement

Comment: which SQL flavor are you using? sql server, mySQL etc. could you please tag that? Also in your example how can value  of `b` can be `19`? it should be `21`

Comment: I don't understand what `intact(goal)` is supposed to be.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name such column represents itself, unchanged or intact, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hi @zealous I'm using Apache Druid, but with several limitations such as the impossibility to use `JOIN` function, as in the `b` value, I need to sum it thus `7 + 12` operation is performed due to agg function `SUM`

Comment: @zealous you were right, sorry I just corrected the addition  
Thank you very much!  
:)

Answer (score 0):

Either include `goal` in the `group by`:

```
SELECT code, SUM(sales) AS total, goal, SUM(sales) * 1.0 / goal as ratio
FROM such_table
GROUP BY code, goal;
```

Or make it the argument to an aggregation function:

```
SELECT code, SUM(sales) AS total, MAX(goal) as goal,
       SUM(sales) * 1.0 / MAX(goal) as ratio
FROM such_table
GROUP BY code;
```

If your data is actually structured this way, you have a problem with your data model.  The `goal` should not be repeated on each row.  You should have one table with one row per `code` and that table should have the `goal`.  Then this table can just contain the sales.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, as for the data model, yes, it is kinda messy but the idea is to sum individual registers with same `code` to add up to `goal` variable, and thank you for your answers both work just fine. Although I need to operate resulting columns from `GROUP BY` to relate them with a percentage, which is where I'm stuck.
Thank you for your time!
:D

Comment: @S_B04 . . . The ratio is just division.  I added that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who contributed to this answer, I wanted to post the solution I use by reading you and surfing the web.
Given the table `such_table`:

```
----------------------
code    sales    goal
----------------------
  b       7       20
  b      12       20
  a       9       15
  b       2       20
  c       4        3
  a       4       15
```

When applying the following query:

```
SELECT
  code,
  SUM(sales) AS total,
  goal
FROM such_table
GROUP BY code, goal;
```

Results in the next table:

```
---------------------
code    total    goal
---------------------
  b      19       20
  a      13       15
  c       4        3
```

Thus in order to display desired results, next query is used:

```
SELECT
  code,
  SUM(sales) AS total,
  goal,
  100 * (SUM(sales) / goal) AS prc_of_goal
FROM such_table
GROUP BY code, goal;
```

Resulting in the following:

```
-----------------------------------
code    total    goal   prc_of_goal
-----------------------------------
  b      19       20       95
  a      13       15       86.67
  c       4        3      133.33
```

Which is what I was looking for
Thank you all
:D